# Convertir fecha y hora a un string en C#

Tags: string, date, querystring

quiero convertir la fecha y la hora en string usando c#, por ejemplo si tengo la fecha 2020-07-12 => 20200712 y en la hora 09:58:16 => 095816

```
public partial class agent : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string NumRef = Request.QueryString["NumRef"];
            string date = Request.QueryString["date"];
            string vCode = Request.QueryString["vCode"];
            string hour = Request.QueryString["hour"];
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("default2.aspx?NumRef=" + NumRef.Text + "&date=" + date.Text + "&vCode=" + vCode.Text + "&hour=" + hour.Text);
    }
}
```

Y en la url ya deben ir los datos pero la fecha sin guiones(-) y la hora sin los puntos (:)

Espero puedan orientarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplica la funcion `toString` a tu fecha tipo `DateTime` de `c#` solo especificas el formato `toString("MMddyyyyHHmmss")`

Ejemplo;

```
string strdate = Request.QueryString["date"];
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(strdate);
date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");//fecha
date.ToString("HHmmss");//hora
```